# Why will Microsoft Word 2011 for Mac only let me type in Times New Roman?

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts

I'm having a problem where Microsoft Word 2011 for Mac will only let me type in Times New Roman. Even if I change the Normal style it still reverts back. I do not want to change the default font for the entire program. What do I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using an international keyboard, try going to **Preferences > Edit** and unchecking **Match font with keyboard**.

This [forum post](http://www.msofficeforums.com/word/11897-cant-get-rid-times-new-roman.html#post38958) set me straight.