# Word automatically switches to Times New Roman whenever I type using a German keyboard layout

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts, microsoft-word-2016

No matter what I do, as soon as I type anything in any word document, the font will switch to Times New Roman.

I can select existing text, chose any font and it will change to that font. But as soon as I type something, that newly typed text will again be in Times New Roman. (Existing text remains unaffected, I can type right in the middle of a word and the new letters will be Times New Roman, while the letters before and after remain whater font was selected before.)

And the problem goes away when I switch to an English keyboard layout. This is not a solution of course, but might help in narrowing down the issue.

The paragraph style I have selected is *Normal* and the font for this style is *Calibri (Body)*.

Here is a video of the problem:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GbprDlAb_Oo

I have completely uninstalled and reinstalled Office, to no avail.

I tried searching online, but I could only find plenty of people who are asking how to configure a default font or how to change fonts, but nothing related to my problem. It might be buried somewhere under all the unrelated search results, though.

**Windows 10 Pro**

- **Version**: 1809
- **Build**: 17763.55

**Microsoft Office 365**

- **Word Version**: 1811
- **Build**: 11029.20079 (Monthy Channel)

I have had this problem for a while now (the video is of an older build (1804 / 9226.2114)) I am actually not sure when it first occurred, as I use Word only a few times a year.

[This question](https://superuser.com/q/530272/882298) seems somewhat relevant, as I am using a German keyboard layout on an English OS and English Office, but it's about Word 2011 on Mac. The *"Match font with keyboard"* option mentioned [in this answer](https://superuser.com/a/530273/882298) doesn't seem to exist in my version of Word.

[This question](https://superuser.com/q/1264529/882298) describes the same problem, however unlike the OP in that question, my "Normal" template does not contain `(Intl) Times New Roman` under *Font*. Instead it simply looks like this:

> Font: (Default) +Body (Calibri), Left
>      Line spacing:  Multiple 1,08 li, Space
>      After:  8 pt, Widow/Orphan control, Style: Show in the Styles gallery

Some further information that might help narrow down this problem:

1) File > Options > Add-ins > "COM Add-ins":
  [image: Screenshot of COM-Addins window, showing one COM Add-in, Visual Studio Tools for Office Design-Time Adaptor for Word]
  - One Add-in: *Visual Studio Tools for Office Design-Time Adaptor for Word*

(2) File > Options > Add-ins > "Templates":
  [image: Screenshot of Templates window, showing empty full path and checkbox marked for "Automatically update document styles"]
  - Full path is empty.
  - "Automatically update document styles" is unchecked.

(3) I don't think that I have any VBA macros, but I

(4) This happens both with .doc and .docx.

(5) In File > Options > Proofing > AutoCorrect Options:
  - AutoFormat As You Type > "Def‌ine styles based on your formatting" is unchecked.
  - Preserve > Styles is checked.

Comment: Have you checked the Font setting on the paragraph style you are using? What is the style name you are using?

Comment: @RichMichaels Thank you for your comment! I have added that info to the question. You can also see in the video the selected style with Calibri as default font.

Comment: Locate your Normal.dotm template, usually it is here: C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates. Try renaming Normal.dotm to oldNormal.dotm, and you'll need to quit Word before doing it.

Comment: @RichMichaels No change :/ Word created a new Normal.dotm, and the behavior remains.

Comment: If you have any add-ins to Word, disable them. Also search your system's folders and make sure there is only the one Normal.dotm template on it. Make sure you check OneDrive also.

Comment: @RichMichaels Thank you for trying to help! I searched with Everything and there is no other Normal.dotm. I don't have OneDrive installed and I don't have any Add-Ins for Word installed.

Comment: @RichMichaels [This question](https://superuser.com/q/530272/882298) seems relevant, but I don't find the option mentioned in the answer. (See also the edit to my question.)

Comment: Checks: (1) In *File > Options > Add-ins > Go...*, select "COM Add-ins" and add a screenshot. (2) Do the same with *Templates > Go...* and verify its full path and if "Automatically update document styles" is unchecked. (3) Do you have any VBA macros? (4) Does this happen with both  `.doc` and `.docx`? (5) In *File > Options > Proofing > AutoCorrect Options... > AutoFormat As You Type*,  that "Def‌ine styles based on your formatting" is unchecked; in *AutoFormat* if Preserve>Styles is checked.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks! I updated the question with the information you asked for.

Comment: Nothing abnormal here. Question: Is your language "English (en-DE)"? If so, try to change it to English United States. Is the font of the Normal style set to Times New Roman? See also [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1335083/8672).

Comment: @harrymc No, switching to English (US) does not help. I followed the steps [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Office-365-ProPlus/Default-Office-theme-uses-Times-New-Roman-everywhere-not-Calibri/td-p/15969) to no avail. Only when I change my system keyboard to a US layout the problem goes away.

Comment: Just to be sure: Your language is pure English (US) and your keyboard is German?

Comment: @harrymc My system language was English (German) with a German keyboard layout. I also had English (US) with an English keyboard layout installed. I just removed the English (German) language completely and changed the keyboard layout for English (US) to German, and voilà, the problem is gone. Thank you for your help! But I had to do this in my system settings, not in the Word options. If you post an answer with this solution, I'll gladly give you the bounty. Well deserved.

Comment: Done as requested.

Comment: I have the same issue using English (US) Keyboard and English (Netherlands) display language. Changing the display language to English (US) seems to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an obscure bug that affects Windows 10 when the language is set to
"English (German)" with a German keyboard layout.

The solution is in Settings to set the language to pure "English (US)",
then add the German keyboard layout.

The reports I have found were specifically for that combination of language
and the German keyboard, but this bug might possibly happen with other languages.
I can only theorize that it relates to some mishandling in Word of such
a language/keyboard combination.

Comment: [ref] "Now i changed my Language Pack to English United States and all workes fine now" https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/my-font-keeps-changing-back-to-timesnewroman/8100077e-dd34-4485-81a1-d2cd131c2dc3

Comment: This also worked for me with "English (Netherlands)" as the OS language.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it really is about the 'input method' (in MS windows, not just MS word), i.e. English (Germany) is causing the problem. Switching to German (Germany) sorts it out - also while editing 'English' text in Word.

[image: Windows input method select]

Answer (score 0):

You can set default font by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, after assigning preferred font hit set as default. This will solves font problem related to the font.

Comment: This does not solve the issue unfortunately.

Comment: This didn't help for me either.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is still remaining in 19h1 aka 1903. 
But simple Solution, just switch the german keyboard from "German QWERTZ" to "German (IBM) QWERTZ".

I tested this on at leased 15 clients and its works still after reboot. 
Could be easiely setup for deployment over MDT and SCCM.

[[image: Language Options]

Answer (score -1):

I had same issue, Word automatically changed font when I typed. So I closed Word program, reopened and the issue got fixed. Got this solution from another website.

Answer (score -1):

as a Mac user, I pressed command and d then made sure I had set calibri as my default for all documents, not just the one I was working on.

Comment: And this solved the problem of a switch to TNR when using a German keyboard layout? If so, please make it clear in your answer.